# Help. Lost my backup phrase, but I have access to my wallet

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery

When I downloaded the wallet on my phone I was  asked to write down a strange, meaningless phrase on a paper so I could access my bitcoins if they were lost, and I did so. I know pretty good why does this exist and understand it's importance, but i'm afraid I've lost the paper on which I wrote the phrase.

Keeping in mind that I STILL HAVE ACCESS to my wallet, Is there any way I could change or recover my phrase?

P.S : Alright, I promise to protect this one with my life.
P.P.S : I really need help. Any sort of help that lets me change or recover my phrase would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You may find https://metasafe.org useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Don't worry.

There is no way to change the "strange, meaningless phrase" (it's called `seed`).

Your private key is generated by the seed, but you can't do it the other direction.

What you could do: Create a new wallet (you can use the same password again), write down the seed of that wallet, send your bitcoins to an adress of the new wallet (should be possible as you remember the password). Result: You have a wallet with bitcoins on its adress(es) AND you have a seed for that.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the solution. I already thought of that but if you say there is no other way, well I guess I must do so.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the wallet you can usually create a new backup which will give you the same phrase. Look in your wallet for options to create recovery phrase or backup current wallet.